Proving the infimum of all open sets containing a given set is an outer measure
My professor has posed this problem in his lecture notes. And has neglected to give a solution. Given a metric space $X$, and a Borel measure $\mu$. Suppose that we define a function as follows:
$$ \mu^*(E) = \inf \{ \mu(U) : E \subset U, U \text{ is open} \} \quad \forall E \subseteq X$$
Prove that $\mu^*$ is an outer measure.
I can easily show non-negativity and monotonicity. But I am struggling on showing countable subaditivity. Any help would be much appreciated.

Do you know that $\mu$ is countably subadditive?

You need to show that $$\mu^* \left( \bigcup_k E_k \right) \le \sum_k \mu^*(E_k)$$ for any countable family $\{E_k\}$ of subsets of $X$.  If $\mu^*(E_k) = \infty$ for some $k$ there is nothing to show. Assume that $\mu^*(E_k) < \infty$ for all $k$.
Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. For each $k$ there exists an open set $U_k \supset E_k$ satisfying $\mu(U_k) < \mu^*(E_k) + \dfrac \epsilon{2^k}$. Since $\bigcup_k E_k \subset \bigcup_k U_k$ and $\bigcup_k U_k$ is open, the countable subadditivity of $\mu$ gives you $$\mu^* \left( \bigcup_k E_k \right) \le \mu^* \left( \bigcup_k U_k \right) \le \sum_k \mu(U_k) < \sum_k \mu^*(E_k) + \epsilon.$$
Now let $\epsilon \to 0^+$.
